# First class Modules with parametric types (The type constructor F.f would escape its scope)

Tags: types, module, ocaml, locally-abstract-type

I am currently playing around with modules, to see in which way they can be used in similar ways to Haskell type classes. Currently I am trying to play around with the functor type class:

```
module type Functor =
   sig
      type 'a f
      val fmap : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a f -> 'b f)
   end


module IdFunc =
   struct
      type 'a f  = Id of 'a
      let fmap f = fun (Id a) -> Id (f a)
      let runId  (Id a) = a
   end

let outmap (module F : Functor) av = F.fmap f av
```

However in this case `outmap` will not be typed correctly, the compiler produces the error `The type constructor F.f would escape its scope`. I know why this error is caused in this case, but I am not sure how to work around it (because type f is parametrized).

I already tried to use locally abstract types:

```
let outmap (type s) (module F : Functor with type 'a f = s) f av = F.fmap f av
```

or

```
let outmap (type a) (type b) (type fa) (type fb) 
 (module F : Functor with type a f = fa type b f = fb) f av = 
 F.fmap f av
```

or

```
let outmap (type s) (module F : Functor with type f = s) f av = F.fmap f av
```

which all just give me various syntax errors or typing errors.

Is there any way to work around this?

In Haskell this would just be:

```
outmap : Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

what would be the equivalent in ocaml (if any)?

==== EDIT ====

I found one way to get something similar to work:

```
module type Functor =
   sig
      type a
      type b
      type af
      type bf
      val fmap : (a -> b) -> (af -> bf)
   end

module type FromTo =
   sig
      type a
      type b
   end

module IdFunc =
   functor (FT : FromTo) -> 
   struct
      type a = FT.a
      type b = FT.b
      type 'a f  = Id of 'a
      type af = a f
      type bf = b f
      let fmap f = fun (Id a) -> Id (f a)
      let runId  (Id a) = a
   end

let outmap (type a') (type b') (type af') (type bf') 
   (module F : Functor 
      with type a  = a'  and
           type b  = b'  and
           type af = af' and
           type bf = bf') 
   f av =  F.fmap f av

module M = IdFunc(struct type a = int type b = string end)

let oi = outmap (module M)

let test = oi (fun _ -> "Test") (M.Id 10)
```

But this looks like a lot of added complexity for something that should probably be much simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot directly express what you are trying to do because it is an example of higher-kinded polymorphism (polymorphism over type constructors) which is not supported in OCaml's core language.

For an explanation of why OCaml's core language cannot support higher-kinded polymorphism see Section 1.1 in [Lightweight higher-kinded polymorphism](http://www.lpw25.net/flops2014.pdf).

Since the module system *does* support higher-kinded polymophism, the usual solution to this problem is to make `outmap` a functor rather than a function.

Alternatively, the paper linked above describes a workaround (implemented in the `higher` library -- available on opam) which essentially uses defunctionalisation at the type-level. Whether this is more convenient than using functors or not depends on your specific use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ideas from the paper mentioned above (assuming you have defined `app` and `Newtype1` as described in the paper or use their `higher` package from opam), you can define you functor as:

```
module type Functor = sig
  type t
  val fmap : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a, t) app -> ('b, t) app
end

module Id = Newtype1(struct type 'a t = 'a end)

module IdFunc : Functor with type t = Id.t = struct
  type t = Id.t
  let fmap f x = x |> Id.prj |> f |> Id.inj
end

let runId (x : ('a, Id.t) app) : 'a = Id.prj x

let outmap (type a)
           (module F : Functor with type t = a)
           f av =
  F.fmap f av
```

For more examples, you can check out https://github.com/hongchangwu/ocaml-type-classes