# Indexing a set using first class module

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I want to index all the elements of the set and store this indexing in a map. A working solution is to extend the Set module and create an inner functor:

```
module Make(M : Set.S) = struct
  include M

  module MakeIndexer(MM : Map.S with type key = elt) = struct
    let index_set set =
      let aux el (ix, acc) =
        (ix + 1, MM.add el ix acc)
      in
      M.fold aux set (0, MM.empty) |> snd
  end
end
```

Now, the use of the inner functor is a little cumbersome, I'd like to use an implementation using first class module. So far I got the following:

```
module Make(M : Set.S) = struct
  include M

  let index_map (module MM : Map.S with type key = elt) set =
    let aux el (ix, acc) =
      (ix + 1, MM.add el ix acc)
    in
    M.fold aux set (0, MM.empty) |> snd
end
```

I obtain the following error message

```
Characters 156-191:
  M.fold aux set (0, MM.empty) |> snd
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type int MM.t
      but an expression was expected of type int MM.t
      The type constructor MM.t would escape its scope
```

I understand that I'm using syntatic sugar and that the module is locally bound in the function, but is there a way to write the function using first class module?

Comment: You can't return a value that has a type local to a function. That's the problem.

Comment: That's what I understood from the error message, but is there a way to describe that the type of the output map depend on the argument module?

Comment: type `t` in `Map.S` is a type constructor, and you want your function to be polymorphic in that type constructor. This is called higher-kinded polymorphism and is not supported in the OCaml core language. [More detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385794/first-class-modules-with-parametric-types-the-type-constructor-f-f-would-escape/24387328#24387328).

Answer (score 1):

## Updated version

If I understand you correctly you want to make index-map algorithm polymorhic w.r.t to mapping structure. Indeed, you need only two things from the whole set of Map operations: inital value and an addition operator. So you can just pass them as a parameter to your function.

```
module Make(T : Set.OrderedType) = struct
  module Set = Set.Make(T)

  let index_map (set : Set.t) (map : 'm) add : 'm =
    let aux el (ix, acc) =
      (ix + 1, add el ix acc) in
    Set.fold aux set (0, map) |> snd
end
```

Comment: Sadly not, the problem then is that you have an associated map module, in the idea the Map could come from anywhere else in the program if the key and elt have the same time (and maybe not the same comparison function)

Answer (score -1):

### Use an array

> Let's say I want to index all the elements of the set and store this indexing in a map.

Your solution is over-complicated.

You should use an array containing the elements of your set instead. If it is sorted in increasing order, then you can find the index of an item in *O(log n)* — which is just as good as what a map offers — and you can find the item bound to an index in *O(1)* — which functionality is not offered by the map.

Using an array would be easier to describe, easier to implement and offer more functionality for the same performance: it is a clean victory.